# Set program language base on installer

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer

I have 2 different project. 1 for English, 1 for japanese

Can I create 1 installer for both language

Ex: when pick English => install English project

when pick japanese => install Japanese project

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fairly simple within Advanced Installer. Just search for the "Translations" page into your project (after you create it) and add all the languages you need your setup project be localized into.

Comment: this is only change language in installer box, not change application UI base on selected language

Comment: if you need to install certain resources (i.e. app resources) conditionally (i.e. depending on the program language) then you can simply add conditions in "Organization" page of your setup project on your features/components;

the condition could make use of "ProductLanguage" prop[erty value

https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/product-language.html